# How to use ternary operator in React native

Tags: css, react-native, react-hooks

am new in React native, i made a simple todo application in this application i add a clear button, my problem is , when i add todo then display clear button otherwiese i don't want it. free feel to ask any question if you have any query.

This is my simple add todo code , in this application i used function component

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button, Alert, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import Header from './Components/Header';
import { AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons';

const App = () => {

  const [text, setText] = React.useState("");
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([])

  const [show, setShow] = React.useState(false);


  // Add a todo
  const addTodo = () => {
    if (text == "") {
      alert("Please Enter Todo");
    }
    else {
      setItems([...items, text]);
      setText('');
    }
  }

  // Delete a todo
  const deleteItem = (id) => {
    const updatedItems = items.filter((elem, ind) => {
      return ind != id;
    })
    setItems(updatedItems);
  }

  // Clear all todo

  const clearAllItems = () => {
    setItems([]);
  }

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <View>
        <Header />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          value={text}
          onChangeText={(e) => setText(e)}
        />
        <Button title="Add +"
          onPress={addTodo}
        />
        <View style={styles.list}>
          {items.map((elem, ind) => {
            return (
              <View key={ind} style={styles.listitem}>
                <Text style={styles.item}>{elem}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.icon} onPress={() => deleteItem(ind)}><AntDesign name="delete" size={24} color="black" /></Text>
              </View>
            )
          })}
        </View>
        {
          show ? items : <Button title="Clear" onPress={clearAllItems} />
        }

      </View>
    </ScrollView>

  )
}

export default App

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  list: {
    marginTop: 20,
    padding: 50,
  },
  item: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    padding: 10,
    marginTop: 10,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderStyle: 'dashed',
    borderColor: 'gray',
    textAlign: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#5ed9db',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: 'black',
    fontSize: 20,
    width: 280
  },
  input: {
    height: 40,
    margin: 12,
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
  },
  listitem: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between'
  },
  icon: {
    marginTop: 10,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'black',
    backgroundColor: '#5edbb3',
    width: 50,
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    alignItems: 'center',
    textAlign: 'center',
    padding: 10
  }
})
```

Comment: Where have you used `setShow` after initializing?

Comment: You need either a flatlist for showing your items or mapping the array to return the desired component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  const [text, setText] = React.useState("");
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([])    

  // Add a todo
  const addTodo = () => {
    if (text == "") {
      alert("Please Enter Todo");
    }
    else {
      setItems([...items, text]);
      setText('');
    }
  }

  // Delete a todo
  const deleteItem = (id) => {
    const updatedItems = items.filter((elem, ind) => {
      return ind != id;
    })
    setItems(updatedItems);
  }

  // Clear all todo

  const clearAllItems = () => {
    setItems([]);
  }

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <View>
        <Header />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          value={text}
          onChangeText={(e) => setText(e)}
        />
        <Button title="Add +"
          onPress={addTodo}
        />
        <View style={styles.list}>
          {items.map((elem, ind) => {
            return (
              <View key={ind} style={styles.listitem}>
                <Text style={styles.item}>{elem}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.icon} onPress={() => deleteItem(ind)}><AntDesign name="delete" size={24} color="black" /></Text>
              </View>
            )
          })}
        </View>
        {
          items.length > 0 && <Button title="Clear" onPress={clearAllItems} />
        }

      </View>
    </ScrollView>

  )
}
```

I don't believe you'll need the state for show, setShow. Let me know if that works.
Ian Vasco mentioned FlatList. You might consider using [FlatList](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist) as I believe it's optimized for React Native.

Comment: You're very welcome. @Ian Vasco did mention FlatList. Although .map will work, I believe FlatList is the better tool for your use case. https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist